# How can i prevent kendo dropdownlist from changing its value on valueChange or selectionChange events in angular 4+

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-dropdown

I have a kendo dropdown list, i am displaying a Dialog confirmation box before changing the dropdown value. It is working fine but the dropdown value is getting changed despite doing anything on the dailog box, How can i stop value changing on dropdownlist.

My Dropdown list with valueChange event.

```
 <kendo-dropdownlist required [data]="responseTypes"
                                [defaultItem]="{responseTypeID: null, responseTypeName: 'Select Response Type'}"
                                [textField]="'responseTypeName'"
                                [valueField]="'responseTypeID'"
                                name="responseTypeId"
                                [(ngModel)]="selectedResponseType"
                                (valueChange)="responseTypeChange($event, this)"
                                #responseTypeIdVar="ngModel" class="form-control" style="width:180px;">
```

responseTypeChange method

```
public responseTypeChange(value: any, data: any): void {
    let changeResponseType: boolean = false; 
    if (this.oldResponseTypeValue != undefined) {
        const dialog: DialogRef = this.dialogService.open({
          title: "Primary Insights",
          content: "Changing response type will remove the options filled, Do you want to continue?",
          actions: [
            { text: "No" },
            { text: "Yes", primary: true }
          ],
          width: 520,
          minWidth: 250
        });

        dialog.result.subscribe((result) => {
          if ((result as any).text === "Yes") {
            //changeResponseType = true;
            this.initializeResponseType(value);
          }
          if ((result as any).text === "No") {
            //changeResponseType = true;
            this.selectedResponseType = this.oldResponseTypeValue;
            this.multipleChoiceResponse.multipleChoiceOptionsArray = data.multipleChoiceResponse.multipleChoiceOptionsArray;
          }
        });
      }
  }
```

Comment: no way for now - https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/1285

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, what you can do is set the value back to the previous one and then open the dialog. In the dialog result handler you set the dropdown value to the new one if the user confirmed the action.

```
public handleValueChange(value: Product): void {
  this.destroyDialog();

  this.value = this.previousValue;
  this.dropDownList.value = this.previousValue;

  this.changeDetector.markForCheck();

  this.dialog = this.dialogService.open({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    content: "Are you sure you want to proceed?",
    actions: [{ text: "No" }, { text: "Yes", primary: true }],
    width: 450,
    height: 200,
    minWidth: 250
  });

  this.dialogSubscription = this.dialog.result
    .pipe(take(1))
    .subscribe(result => {
      if (!(result instanceof DialogCloseResult) && result.text === "Yes") {
        this.previousValue = value;
        this.dropDownList.value = value;
        this.value = value;
      }
    });
}
```

You can see a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tkm9ay-jrdu2f?file=app/app.component.ts) based on a demo provided by the Kendo team.

**Note:** You will have to make sure that any components that are bound to the same property as the dropdown check if the value was actually changed to prevent redundant actions.